# Vert.x JWT auth gives Forbidden access

Tags: java, vert.x, java-11

**SCENARIO**

I am calling this method inside the `start()` of my http server verticle:

```
private void setupAuth(Router router) {
    // Secure access key
    var config = new JWTAuthOptions()
      .setKeyStore(new KeyStoreOptions()
        .setType("jceks")
        .setPath("C:\\Users\\3587741\\Desktop\\Projects\\P_Gatlin\\jwt\\keystore.jceks")
        .setPassword("secret")
      );

    // Setup the secure route
    authProvider = JWTAuth.create(vertx, config);
    router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create());
    router.route().handler(SessionHandler.create(LocalSessionStore.create(vertx)).setAuthProvider(authProvider));

    // Redirect to a login page if the user is NOT logged
    var redirectAuthHandler = RedirectAuthHandler.create(authProvider, RouteNames.LOGIN_ADMIN, "/");

    // Secure every page that starts with "/admin/..."
    router.route("/admin/*").handler(redirectAuthHandler);
    router.post(RouteNames.LOGIN_CHECKER).handler(FormLoginHandler.create(authProvider));
  }
```

I need to have the `/admin/*` path to be safe. The above implementation has been almost totally copy pasted from the official [documentation](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/java/#_creating_an_auth_handler). I have used this line to generate the key:

```
keytool -genkeypair -keystore keystore.jceks -storetype jceks -storepass secret -keyalg EC -keysize 256 -alias ES512 -keypass secret -sigalg SHA512withECDSA -dname "CN=,OU=,O=,L=,ST=,C=" -validity 360
```

From the above, the password is `secret` and alias is `es512`. This is the content of the login page

```
  <form action="/login-auth" method="POST">
    <div class="credential">
      <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
      <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />

      <input type="submit" value="OK" />
    </div>
  </form>
```

where `/login-auth` is the value of `RouteNames.LOGIN_CHECKER` inside `router.post(RouteNames.LOGIN_CHECKER).handler(FormLoginHandler.create(authProvider));`

---

In my webpage I try to access `http://localhost/admin/test` and I am correctly redirected to `/login` page:

[image]

Why do I get this message

> Forbidden

when I try to access? The alias and the password are correct, I have also tested them with keytool and they match (I have used them in the command to generate the jceks). What is wrong?

Am I failing to use the JWT auth in some way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing 2 incompatible things here.

- `FormAuthHandler` function is to redirect your browser to an HTML page where login/password are asked to the end user. This is what you're observing.
- `JWTHandler` function is to validate JWT tokens.

So when your browser submits the form to the server, it sends a form (with username/password), not a JWT token. Since the token is missing you will get a forbidden error code.